# Logging into chat is really hard

Tags: bug, chat

I'm having a lot of issues with the chat site claiming that I'm not logged in. Logging into a regular Stack Exchange site such as Code Golf works fine, but the login does not carry over to chat. Moreover, clicking the link to a login page from there and logging in often has no effect. I have to try it 3 or 4 times before it will stop saying I am not logged in.

Browser: Firefox

OS: Windows 8

Comment: Are you using httpseverywhere?

Comment: @rene No; in fact I have no plugins whatsoever.